# Set state objects directly and call setState

Tags: reactjs

In my component existing user data are edited. Each user dataset has plenty of properties. Is it ok to set a value of an object like in the example below. Or how would be correct?

```
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      user: {age: 0, id: 0, weight: 0, size: 0, ...},
    };
  },

  componentWillReceiveProps: function (nextProps) {
    this.setState({
      user: nextProps.user
    });
  },

  editUserAge(age) {
    this.state.user.age = age;

    this.setState({
      user: this.state.user
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right approach would be to avoid mutating state directly like this

```
editUserAge(age) {
    let user = {...this.state.user};
    user.age = age;

    this.setState({ user });
  }
```

Comment: Note that the object spread syntax requires the Babel stage 3 preset, as it's not been standardized yet. You can use `Object.assign` instead, if for whatever reason you can't add the preset.

Answer (score 2):

You can use functional version of `setState` when the value you want to set is related to some value from state. This way if state changes in the middle of your method *(because `setState` is async it can happen anytime because of any other method)* your current change does not get affected. Also you need to avoid mutating previous state values. You can use [`Object.assign(..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for that.

**Example**

```
editUserAge(age) {
  this.setState((prevState) => {
    let newUser = Object.assign({}, prevState.user, {age: age});
    return { user: newUser };
  });
}
```